# How can I eliminate the space between two lines on the title page? I have tried using the Vspace command, but it doesn't work

Tags: vspace

```
\documentclass[12pt, twoside]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[English]{babel}
\usepackage[width=17cm,height=22cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[square,numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage[nottoc,numbib]{tocbibind}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\setlength{\headheight}{20pt}
\linespread{1.1}
\fancyhead[E]{\thepage\hfill \textit{\nouppercase{\rightmark}}}
\fancyhead[O]{\textit{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}\hfill\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\cfoot{}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,mathtools}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\newcommand{\bD}{\mathbb{D}}
\newcommand{\bR}{\mathbb{R}}
\newcommand{\bZ}{\mathbb{Z}}
\newcommand{\bC}{\mathbb{C}}
\newcommand{\bN}{\mathbb{N}}
\newcommand{\cH}{\mathcal{H}}
\newcommand{\cA}{\mathcal{A}}
\renewcommand{\phi}{\varphi}
\newcommand{\arctanh}{\operatorname{arctanh}}
\newcommand{\sinc}{\operatorname{sinc}}
\newcommand{\eqdef}{\coloneqq}
\newcommand{\eps}{\varepsilon}
\newcommand{\de}{\delta}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{thm}{Teorema}
\newtheorem{prop}[thm]{Proposición}
\newtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lema}
\newtheorem{conj}[thm]{Conjetura}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{defn}[thm]{Definición}
\newtheorem{cor}[thm]{Corolario}
\newtheorem{ex}[thm]{Ejemplo}



\usepackage{xcolor}
\newenvironment{egornote}{\color{blue}}{}

\title{ hjk}
\author{ \\
[1cm]{Directores de tesis:
}}
\date{July 2021}
\begin{document}


   \begin{titlepage}
   \hspace*{-0.5in}
        \thispagestyle{empty}
        \begin{minipage}[c][0.17\textheight][c]{0.25\textwidth}
            \begin{center}
                \includegraphics[width=4.0cm, height=4.0cm]{imagenes/xc.jpg}
            \end{center}
        \end{minipage}
        \begin{minipage}[c][0.195\textheight][t]{0.75\textwidth}
            \begin{center}
                \vspace{0.3cm}
                \Large{\textbf{\textcolor{black} { University }}}\\[0.1mm]
                \vspace{0.3cm}
                \rule[3mm]{140mm}{3pt}
                \vspace{-0.1cm}
                \hspace{13pt}\rule[3mm]{130mm}{2pt}
                \vspace{-0.5cm}
        \normalsize{\textbf{\fontsize{40}{50}{Master Thesis}}}\\[ .2in]%[0.5cm]
            \end{center}
        \end{minipage}
\hspace*{-0.1in}
        \begin{minipage}[c][0.81\textheight][t]{0.25\textwidth}
            \vspace*{5mm}
            \begin{center}
                \hskip2.0mm
                \rule[-1cm]{6pt}{15cm} 
                \vspace{5mm}
                \hskip2pt
                \rule[0cm]{3pt}{14cm}
                \hskip1mm
                \rule[2cm]{2pt}{12cm} \\
                \vspace{5mm}
                \includegraphics[width =3cm, height=3.5cm]{imagenes/vb.jpg}
            \end{center}
        \end{minipage}
        \begin{minipage}[c][0.81\textheight][t]{0.75\textwidth}
            \begin{center}
               % \vspace{1cm}
                %{\large\scshape Master Thesis }\\[.2in]

               % \vspace{1cm}            

               % \textsc{\LARGE 
%\hspace{1.5cm}E\hspace{1.5cm}S\hspace{1.5cm}I\hspace{1.5cm}S}\\[0.5cm]
               \Large{\textbf{\textcolor{black} {topic}}}\\[0.5cm]
                 \normalsize{\textbf Submitted by :}\\[0.5cm]
                 \normalsize{\textbf {}}\\[0.5cm]
                 \normalsize{\textbf {Enroll\# : }}\\[0.5cm]          

                \vspace{0.3cm}

                \large{\emph Supervisors:\\[0.3cm] }\large{\textbf {Prof \\[0.2cm]}}
        
            \large{\textbf {Prof}}\\[.2in]

                \vspace{0.3cm}
                \begin{center}
                %\vspace{0.5cm}
                \normalsize{\textbf Thesis submitted }\\[.2in]
                \vspace{0.3cm}      
                 \end{center}
                \begin{center}
                %\vspace{0.5cm}
                \Large{\textbf{\textcolor{black} Institute of Earth and Environmental Sciences
}}\\[.2in]
                 \end{center}
                \normalsize{\textbf{place}}{ }\normalsize{\textbf{\today}}
            \end{center}
        \end{minipage}
    \end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please add the code for your current title page, including the documentclass and all the packages that you use. Of course you can replace sensitive or personal information if needed.

Comment: \rule[3mm]{140mm}{3pt}
 \vspace{-0.5cm}
 \hspace{13pt}\rule[3mm]{130mm}{2pt}
  \vspace{-0.5cm}
  \normalsize{\textbf{\fontsize{40}{50}{Master Thesis}}}\\[ .2in]

Comment: \documentclass[12pt, twoside]{book}

Comment: @Umer please add a short, but compilable test document to your question. As you can see, comments are not good for sharing code, no line breaks etc.

Comment: Please edit the code into your question instead of in comments. Also it would be easier to reproduce if the code was complete, including `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}`, and anything else needed to be able to compile the document without errors resulting in the title page.

Comment: It's mean i add the entire code for my title page or only a selective portion

Comment: a complete file people can run through latex to see your ruls and test answers

Comment: `\rule[3mm]{140mm}{3pt} \vspace{-0.5cm} \hspace{13pt}\rule[3mm]{130mm}{2pt}` adds -0.5 cm after the second rule not between them, use `\rule[3mm]{140mm}{3pt} \par\vspace{-0.5cm} \hspace*{13pt}\rule[3mm]{130mm}{2pt}`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment. I add the vspace command after the second rule but still same issue. Thanks

Comment: size commads do not take an argument  `\Large{..}`  , `\normalsize{..}`  should not havee `{}` also we can not use ` \includegraphics[width=4.0cm, height=4.0cm]{imagenes/xc.jpg}`

Comment: I add the entire code for the title page.

Comment: Welcome. // Please delete packages from your code which are not needed to show your problem. After that cleanup (and update of your question) it may be a good idea to add a screenshot to your question "this is how it looks like after compile". // Also, kindly review the comments made so far, and enter relevant information and add-ons to your question. It's always difficult, to get peoples intention from a title and some long code only. Future readers will have a hard time, else. Thanks

Comment: ". I add the vspace command after the second rule" no you want vspace between the rules, but as I wrote, put `\par` (or a blank line) before `\vspace`

Answer (score 2):

A more reasonable example document would be

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

xxx

\rule[3mm]{140mm}{3pt} \vspace{-0.5cm} \hspace{13pt}\rule[3mm]{130mm}{2pt}

yyy

\end{document}
```

which makes

[image]

You have added both rules in the same paragraph,  they only appear one above the other due to line breaking so the `\hspace` is discarded and the `\vspace` is inserted after the line, so raises yyy.

You want to stack vertically so use separate paragraphs, and use `\hspace*`
if you want space at the start of a line.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

xxx

\rule[3mm]{140mm}{3pt} 

\vspace{-0.25cm}
\hspace*{13pt}\rule[3mm]{130mm}{2pt}

yyy

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. it looks perfect. Thank you very much once again,

Answer (score 1):

`\noindent` removes the paragraph indentation. Don't use `\hspace{-<length>}`, which I think was meant to negate the indentation.

If you want to stack things vertically, such as texts, minipages, tables, figures etc., you have to form separate paragraphs. Either leave an empty line(s) (which is(are) converted to `\par`) or add `\par`, explicitly. I think that is one of your major problems.

If you want exact spacing between lines specified by `\vspace{}`, you may want to turn off extra glue LaTeX adds between paragraph lines. Either add `\nointerlineskip` before the next `\rule` or `\offinterlineskip` as the first thing in the current environment, such as `minipage`--don't use it globally because it affects everything in that scope!

Any item that requires width as a parameter, say `\rule` or `\includegraphics`, can take a relative `width` to its parent box, in your case the width of `minipage` if you use `X\linewidth`--particularly `1\linewidth` or simply `\linewidth` means the full width of a parent box.

I removed all unnecessary packages. Currently, `minipage`s do not add to the `\textwidth`. I left a stretchable gap by inserting `\hfill` between them. If you like, change proportions of both minipages. When they add to `1\textwidth`, you no longer need `\hfill` but keep `%` after the first `minipage`! Also, `minipage` adapts height of its box based on the content. There is no need for extra parameters if you expect alignment w.r.t middle points.

This is one example solution for your title

```
\documentclass[12pt, twoside]{book}
\usepackage[width=17cm,height=22cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[draft]{graphicx}   % Remove [draft] to render images

%%% For demostration
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.2pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{blue}}


\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
  \thispagestyle{empty}
  
  \noindent
  \begin{minipage}{0.25\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, height=\linewidth]{imagenes/xc.jpg}
  \end{minipage}%  <--- Keep % here to avoid extra space
  \hfill
  \begin{minipage}{0.7\textwidth}
    \offinterlineskip   % all \vspace'es mean exact space
    \centering
    {\Large\textbf{University}}
    \par\vspace{0.15in}\rule{\linewidth}{3pt}
    \par\vspace{1mm}\rule{0.9\linewidth}{2pt}
    \par\vspace{0.25in}{\fontsize{40}{50}\selectfont\textbf{Master Thesis}}
  \end{minipage}
\end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```

[image]